# How do i split a name string into two textboxes

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, split, substring

**This is in c#**

I have 2 textboxes for firstname and lastname. I wish to split a name string which into the appropriate textbox which it belongs to, but the problem is there are many combinations of what the name string can be. It can either be, "Mr John Smith", or "Mr Smith", for these the result i get is ok, the problem im having now is when splitting a string such as "Mrs and Mrs Smith" The split does not work as planned as i get "Mr" in the first textbox and i get "and Mrs Smith" in the second textbox.

Here is my function below, can anyone help as I will like to have the firstname textbox with the firsy name if there is one and the lastname textbox with value of the lastname if the string is something like "Mr and Mrs Smith" or "Mr & Mrs John Smith"

```
string name = "Mr and Mrs Smith";
string[] titles = new string[] {"Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Ms", "Master", "Mr and Mrs", 
           "Mr & Mrs", "Lady", "Lord", "Prof", "Proffessor", "Ma'am", "Madame"};
foreach (string title in titles)
{
  if (name.StartsWith(title) && !name.Equals(title, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    var titleLength = title.Length;
    var titlelessName = name.Substring(titleLength + 1);
    var spaceIndex = titlelessName.IndexOf(' ');
    if (spaceIndex > -1 && spaceIndex >= 0)
    {
      var firstName = titlelessName.Substring(0, spaceIndex);
      var lastName = titlelessName.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
      txtFname.Text = firstName;
      txtLname.Text = lastName;
    }
  }
  else if (!name.StartsWith(title) && name.Contains(' '))
  {
    var firstName = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(' '));
    var lastName = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(' '));
    txtFname.Text = firstName;
    txtLname.Text = lastName;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `dr` and `rev`!

Comment: "Mr and Mrs Smith" is known as the "salutation". It is more usual/easier to derive the salutation from the individual name fields (e.g., title, first name, surname). Is this an option for you?

Comment: Just imagine that you have to handle things like "His Hollynes John Paul the Secund" or "Su Alteza Real Don Juan Carlos de Borbón y Borbón-Dos Sicilias". What you need is called a "natural language parser", a problem still waiting for a polynomial or better solution xD

Comment: What about Mr & Mr, or Mrs and Mrs?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to handle all instances of your input as something which comes in the form of `{firstname} {lastname}`. Now the reality is that you accept a whole lot of input that comes in differing shapes and sizes. So you could either bash your head bloody trying to force your input to behave like you want it, or you can adapt and change the solution to fit the input.

You will *never* be able to figure out all possible combinations of first name, last name and title. What about people who enter `Duke Leopold von Haussknauf, Phd`?

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but you should consider changing the solution in some way. Maybe present it in a single box instead, or make people input title, first and last name separately to begin with?

Comment: This isnt an input thing, its of passing a value from somewhere where it already exist into the textbox. in order to use it for an external software which needs the firstname and lastname in order to work

Comment: If you have no control over how or what users can input as their name, and you absolutely need to be able to split it on firstname/lastname, then you are in for one interesting ride. I wish you all the best, but I can't help you.

Comment: @ifelabolz: fair enough, but Anders' point still stands. You are going to have to accept that any solution you have is going to be less than 100% accurate and you (or some poor soul) is going to have to manually check the data for accuracy.

Comment: @MattBurland I understand that my solution will not be 100% accurate but this will help in some situations,

Comment: Tahnks @AndersHolmström :) appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the logic of you loop isn't correct.

You first check if the title matches, if it doesn't you split on the space in the name. The problem here is that you shouldn't do that until you've checked *every* title.

What's worse, is that if the title in you name isn't the last title in your array, then the next cycle through the array will end up doing the second condition in your loop and overwrite the correct behavior. You need to exit the loop once you've found a matching title!

So, something like this (untested code):

```
    string name = "Mr and Mrs Smith";
    string[] titles = new string[] {"Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Ms", "Master", "Mr and Mrs", "Mr & Mrs", "Lady", "Lord", "Prof", "Proffessor", "Ma'am", "Madame"};
    var sortedTitles = from s in titles
         orderby s.Length descending
         select s;
    bool foundTitle = false;
    foreach (string title in sortedTitles)
    {
        if (name.StartsWith(title) && !name.Equals(title, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var titleLength = title.Length;
            var titlelessName = name.Substring(titleLength + 1);
            var spaceIndex = titlelessName.IndexOf(' ');
            if (spaceIndex > -1 && spaceIndex >= 0)
            {
                var firstName = titlelessName.Substring(0, spaceIndex);
                var lastName = titlelessName.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
                txtFname.Text = firstName;
                txtLname.Text = lastName;
            }
            foundTitle = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!foundTitle && name.Contains(' '))
    {
        var firstName = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(' '));
        var lastName = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(' '));
        txtFname.Text = firstName;
        txtLname.Text = lastName;
    }
```

And, of course, this isn't taking into account that your list of titles is far from exhaustive and doesn't include a lot of varieties that you might encounter. What about `Mr. and Mrs. Smith`?

Comment: i have added the bool variable and also the break, but this only removes the Mr from the string "Mr and Mrs Smith", so the txtFName has "and" as its value, and the txtLName has "Mrs Smith" as its value, I wish to just have Smith in the txtLName

Comment: And Yeah thanks for reminding me abou the period after the prefix, forgot about that.

Comment: @ifelabolz: Yeah, you problem is that `Mr` is a substring of `Mr and Mrs`. What you need to do is check the *most specific cases first* by rearranging your array so that the most specific cases (`Mr and Mrs`) occurs before (`Mr`).

Comment: @ifelabolz: I've updated my code to sort the list of titles first. Checking the longest strings first should solve the substring problem. Of course, it would be more efficient to just put the list in the right order to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

i Feel something inapproprite in your assumption 
for ex : Mr Smith show Mr as First name which incrrect
i suggest using alternative way to input your data such as dropdown  for mr, mrs ...  etc
think more about your requirments